# how exactly insert of map exactly work in c++?

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

I'm trying to reimplement the map container in c++ by myself but I get stuck in the `insert` method.

NOTE: I know that map uses a self-balancing tree (Red-black Tree) so when You insert a new element you need to respect the binary search tree rules.

now my question is :

the map in (C++98) has 3 insert member functions

```
single element (1)  pair<iterator,bool> insert (const value_type& val);

with hint (2)       iterator insert (iterator position, const value_type& val);

range (3)           template <class InputIterator>
                    void insert (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

the single element (1) is clear.

but the second one is not.

I wanna know how the hint is used and how can I check if the position was given to me respects the rules of the tree or not and how can I fix it.

NOTE 2: This is based on c++98 I know that this changed in C++11.

Comment: Do you know _how_ the `std::map` is implemented? I.e. do you know what a red-black tree is?

Comment: @Darth-CodeX how does that help?

Comment: @Darth-CodeX no it's not, it's just the header. Furthermore, the OP is asking for an explanation. He/she doesn't want to have to read 50000 lines of code. Moreover: re-implementing existing code can be a good exercise.

Comment: [here's the libstdc++ implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_tree.h#L2173), looks like it basically checks whether the hint is in the right place and otherwise finds the right insertion position itself

Answer (score 0):

The hint overloads have tighter complexity requirements when the hint is correct. If the hint is incorrect, it is ignored.

> ### Complexity
>
> Amortized constant if the insertion happens in the position just *after* the hint, logarithmic in the size of the container
> otherwise.

If you already know (or even have a good guess) where the value you are inserting should go, e.g. you are inserting a sequence of already sorted values, you can use the hint overload as an optimisation.